# How to connect NFS server from lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, nfs

I am working on a POC where i need to configure NFS server in AWS lambda function. I tried some libraries like subprocess but it needs root permissions to perform commands on server, which i dont have.

There is another library pyNfsClient, but couldn’t find documentation for this